# Проблема компиляции проекта: error C3861: cbrt: идентификатор не найден

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, математика, visual-studio-2012

Использую библиотеку `math.h` и в ней для нахождения кубического корня есть функция `cbrt();`
Только вот при компиляции Visual Studio говорит: error C3861: cbrt: идентификатор не найден.

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795, x=0.25, y=1.31, a=3.5, b=0.9, P;
    printf("Вы запустили программу для решения задачи 1 из лабораторной 1! \n");
    printf("Программа начинает расчет, ожидайте... \n");
    P=fabs((pow(sin(a*pow(x,3)+b*pow(y,2)-a*b),3))/(cbrt(pow((a*x*3+b*pow(y,2)-a),2)+PI)))+tan(a*pow(x,3)+b*pow(y,2)-a*b);
    printf("Ответ для Задачи 1: %d \n", P);
    return 0;
}
```

Как решать проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно он споткнулся. Потому что эта функция находиться в другом заголовчном файле - amp_math.h ([пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308365.aspx)).

Comment: А вот в ubuntu все работает (правда c `#include <math.h>), и  gcc и  g++. 

    gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 

Даже libm подключать оказывается (вот тут я удивился!) не надо.

Comment: это все, конечно, весьма здорово, но чести разработчикам не делает - нужно помнить, что подключать необходимо amp_math.h а не math.h, не забыть про  пространство имен Concurrency::precise_math, плюс еще сама функция объявлена с __GPU_ONLY, он же restrict(amp). Не знаю, требует ли стандарт объявлять функции в конкретных заголовочных файлах, но сам по себе такой разброд несколько удивляет.

Comment: >> Ну а упрекнуть vc++ в хорошей поддержке этого стандарта до сих пор довольно трудно

 а  по стандарту они должны быть в cmath (стандарт 26.8.9). Майкрософт всегда трактовали стандарт так, как им нужно было.

Comment: После всего, я все-таки взял именно программу ТС и g++. Все компилируется, кроме ошибки в printf()... (там %d надо на %f заменить).

--

@MDev, бросайте творения Б.Гейтса!

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, с чем связано отсутствие этой функции, но попробуйте вот так:

```
#define cbrt(x) pow((x), 1.0/3)
```

Вообще cbrt есть в С99 и в C++TR1, который, кажется, как раз вошел в C++11. Ну а упрекнуть vc++ в хорошей поддержке этого стандарта до сих пор довольно трудно

Comment: отсутствие связано видимо с тем, что эта функция из с++11.

Comment: не знаю как студия, но gcc если его не попросить явно, то он не будет использовать новый стандарт. Возможно у студии тоже.

Comment: не думаю. Во всяком случае мой vc++ сейчас без проблем сожрал вот это: 

    auto fn = []() { return 4; };
    cout << fn() << endl;

а вот об cbrt споткнулся